Give Flink type information to serialize accumulator object without Kryo
I have a custom AggregateFunction with signature like so:
public class CustomAggregateFunction
    implements AggregateFunction<CustomInput, AggregationAccumulator, CustomOutput> { code...}

My AggregationAccumulator is a simple object containing some maps, with the Lombok @Data annotation
  @Data
  public static class AggregationAccumulator {
    private Map<String, Long> customMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

However, Flink is saying that 13:18:50,091 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - Field AggregationAccumulator#customMap will be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution.
How can I provide the type info so that it wouldn't use Kryo?

You can use add a @TypeInfo annotation to the map, and provide an appropriate TypeInfoFactory implementation. Something like this:
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.MapTypeInfo;

public class AccumulatorWithMap {

    @TypeInfo(MapTypeInfoFactory.class)
    private Map<String, Long> customMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public AccumulatorWithMap() { }

    public Map<String, Long> getCustomMap() {
        return customMap;
    }

    public void setCustomMap(Map<String, Long> customMap) {
        this.customMap = customMap;
    }
    
    public static class MapTypeInfoFactory<K, V> extends TypeInfoFactory<Map<K, V>> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public TypeInformation<Map<K, V>> createTypeInfo(
                Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {
            TypeInformation<K> keyType = (TypeInformation<K>)genericParameters.get("K");
            TypeInformation<V> valueType = (TypeInformation<V>)genericParameters.get("V");

            if (keyType == null) {
                throw new InvalidTypesException(
                        "Type extraction is not possible on Map"
                                + " type as it does not contain information about the 'key' type.");
            }

            if (valueType == null) {
                throw new InvalidTypesException(
                        "Type extraction is not possible on Map"
                                + " type as it does not contain information about the 'value' type.");
            }
            
            return new MapTypeInfo<K, V>(keyType, valueType);
        }
    }

    
}

To verify, use:
PojoTestUtils.assertSerializedAsPojoWithoutKryo(AccumulatorWithMap.class);


Thanks for the answer, I took a look at the types in Flink's typeutils, for an use case like a priority queue, are there datatypes that could meet the requirements or is it right now not supported?

You could register a custom serializer (via Kryo would be easiest) for a PriorityQueue. But note that accumulators work best when they reduce results. If you keep pruning results in the PriorityQueue, then maybe it's OK, but if you're just adding items, skip the aggregate and use a ProcessWindowFunction. Note that if the backend is RocksDB you'll be deserializing and re-serializing the PriorityQueue for every element.

I see, the point of using a priority queue is to implement a "top n" like functionality for aggregation. (i.e. user can configure the top n amount before the job runs) Would you recommend another solution to this problem?

I'd have an array of size top-N, keep it sorted once it is full, and compare each new element with the last one to see if you should replace it/re-sort.

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a go at it :)
